# Java Image resizing (3 sizes) upload each to Amazon S3

Tags: java, image, grails, amazon-s3, imagemagick

I'm using grails with jetS3t to upload an image to S3, this works fine.

But now I need to re-size the image (thumbnail, small and medium) and upload them all to S3.

So far I'm thinking about using ImageMagick, But don't know which is the best way to approach the resizing.

Should I:

Upload original to S3, 
then re-size using the URL received from S3(another download), and upload the re-sized image to S3, (x3)

**OR**

Upload and use image bytes in memory, do all the resizing, upload the 3 re-sized photos and the original to S3

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your quality requirements and memory availability.

If you want the resized images to be good quality then using ImageMagick is probably a good option but that requires the source image to be saved locally on disk. On the other hand, you won't need to store all images in memory. [Im4Java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) worked very well for me as an interface to IM.

Using the Java `Graphics` package and `BufferedImage` class you can do an in-memory operation but this might not produce as good quality images.

Comment: hello @mlforyan, how can i do `in-memory` operations using `BuggeredImage` ?